# Bootstrap v3 and Kendo UI Grid 100% height

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I recently started working on a new project and this time around, I started off with a clean [INSPINIA v2.7 theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S). I used an empty page template from that theme and started building a simple search page with some filters and a functioning Kendo Grid.

Now, this website will be published to two orientation of screens: Landscape 1920 x 1080 and Portrait 1600 x 2560. I need to make the Kendo Grid behave accordingly. I google myself to this guide: [Resize and Expand the Kendo UI Grid to 100% Height](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/resize-grid-when-the-window-is-resized). I see that the first case is what I need. But there is a very simple container hierarchy there and the demo works very well.

In a bootstrap powered website, the hierarchy is not that simple.

Here is the _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using DA.Services.IBS.Web.FinancePortalFull.Helpers

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title | Finance System</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Add local styles, mostly for plugins css file -->
        @if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
        {
            @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
        }

        <!-- Add jQuery Style direct - used for jQGrid plugin -->
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Primary Inspinia style -->
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/font-awesome/css")
    </head>

    <body class="md-skin">
        <!-- Wrapper-->
        <!-- PageClass give you ability to specify custom style for specific view based on action -->
        <div id="wrapper" class="@Html.PageClass()">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

            <!-- Page wraper -->
            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg @ViewBag.SpecialClass">

                <!-- Top Navbar -->
                @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

                <!-- Main view  -->
                @RenderBody()

                <!-- Footer -->
                @Html.Partial("_Footer")

            </div>
            <!-- End page wrapper-->
        </div>
        <!-- End wrapper-->

        <!-- Section for main scripts render -->
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
        @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/slimScroll")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inspinia")

        <!-- Handler for local scripts -->
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>

</html>
```

And below is the View itself. I have tried to follow the guide on the kendo link by adding the parent div at different levels but the div and the grid within doesn't render 100% at all.

```
@model DA.Services.IBS.Web.FinancePortalFull.Models.EpayTransactionFilterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Filter";
}

<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">...</ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">...</div>
</div>

<div  class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("FilterReport", "EpayReconcile")">
        <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <div class="row">...</div>
        </div>

        <div id="parent">
            <div class="ibox">
                <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.SearchResults).Name("GridSearchResults")...)
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/dataPickerStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/chosen/chosenStyles")

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #parent,
        #GridSearchResults {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-width: 0;
            height: 100%; /* DO NOT USE !important for setting the Grid height! */
        }

        html
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            font: 13px sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/dataPicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/chosen")

    <script type="text/javascript">           
        var gridElement = $("#GridSearchResults");

        function resizeGrid() {
            gridElement.data("kendoGrid").resize();
        }

        $(window).resize(function(){
            resizeGrid();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Also, just for reference, the two screenshots from respective screens:

[image: 1920 x 1080]

[image: 1600 x 2560]

- I need to know how to make the grid and the required containers and divs expand vertically as per viewport
- If this is successful, I'll attempt to deal with dynamic page sizing so that maximum data can be displayed

**Update:**
I have this dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@DoomerDGR8/owoSeN
It works perfectly keeping performance in mind. I just need to make it work for all the containers and panels starting from _Layout.cshtml all the way down to my cshtml.

**Update 2:**

I added this style to the target view with the grid:

```
<style>
    #GridSearchResults {
        border-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }

    .fill {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    html
    {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Also, modified script, view with grid only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setPageSize();
    });

    function resizeGrid() {
        var gridElement = $("#GridSearchResults");
        // console.log(gridElement);
        gridElement.data("kendoGrid").resize();
        setPageSize();
    }

    function setPageSize(){
        var grid = $("#GridSearchResults").data("kendoGrid");
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        //Custom Logic for pageSize
        if (windowHeight >= 1200) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(40);
        }
        else if (windowHeight >= 1000) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(35);
        }
        else if(windowHeight >= 900){
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(30);
        }
        else if(windowHeight >= 700){
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(25);
        }
        else if(windowHeight >= 400){
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(20);
        }else{
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(10);
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizeGrid();
    });
</script>
```

I still get no resizing effect and the grid remains fixed width as shown in earlier screenshots yet the JS is working. Here is what chrome inspects and it is all wrong as my height directives are being overridden at various places:

[image: Inspect Result]

You'll notice I added the fill class to the page wrapper in _layout.cshtml that will only get applied if user is on the target view where .fill is defined.

No avail.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you are after: http://dojo.telerik.com/iWIXa/11 if it is I can expand on it and add it as a possible solution. (its some code I use for my projects to control grids and resizing).

Comment: I think you will need to set an absolute height of a parental container: https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-100-height

When playing in the dojo I can get 100% IF there exists a container with absolute height. Setting all to 100% results in a small grid.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I found and implemented a similar dojo in my given code. Yes, I'd like to get help in that regard.

Comment: I have this one:http://dojo.telerik.com/@DoomerDGR8/owoSeN Now I need (help) to adjust it in my container/panel setup

Comment: If you have applied the code to change the height automatically on resize (which you say is working) what is not working?

Comment: @DavidShorthose the grid resizes trigger on windows resize is working. But the grid or the hierarchy of panels/containers are not accepting the 100 height CSS fix so nothing happens.